# Samsung Galaxy 2 (Jelly Bean 4.1.2) In the stock "Phone" app, on the "Keypad" tab, how can you enter a "space" character?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, keyboard, calls

I was wondering if there is a way to enter a **"space"** character on the keypad in the keypad tab in the Phone app.

For example, I have 3 different "Mike" contacts:

Mike Smith
Mike Jones
Mike Rothe

In the keypad, when I type "6453" (mike), it then shows the first contact "Mike Smith", and gives me the option to press the "3" button next to "Mike Smith" to see my other contacts with "Mike" as the first name.

I would like to be able to press "6453" and then a **"space"** character, and then "5" ( J ), so it narrows it down to "Mike Jones", instead of making me go through the "Mike"'s to find "Mike Jones"

I can't figure out how to punch in a **"space"** though. Is it possible?

If not, I would be willing to download a better "Phone" app than the 4.1.2 stock phone app, if that would help.

Comment: Isn't the "space key" usually assigned to `1` there? Maybe you could try `6453 1 5` for `mike j`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not specifically the Phone app. You can't enter a space into any field where the app has said it's expecting you to type a phone number.

On the Samsung dialer, you can use a ***** to match a space in a contact's name e.g. 6453*56637 to match Mike Jones. I don't have an S2 to check this on, but that's how the dialer on the S3 works, and I'd expect they're both the same.